# Collision Between two sprites - Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I have an image of a ufo and a missile. I'm trying to get it to where if the missile hits the ufo they both would explode and disappear and then a few moments later another ufo would respawn but the collision code isn't working. can someone explain to me how to make the code work?

```
pygame.display.init()
pygame.font.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
ufo = pygame.image.load("ufo.png")
rocket = pygame.image.load("rocket.png")
done = False
debug = False
fontObj = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier New", 20)

#Making my Empty Lists
missiles = [] #[x,y]
ufo_list = [] #[x,y,hspeed]
particle_list = []

#UFO Respawn Info
ufoRespawn = True
ufoHits = 0
ufoSpawnTimer = 0.0
ufoSpeed = 500.0

#MISSILE Info
launchX = 400
launchY = 550
missileSpeed = 100.0
missileDirection = 0

#creating the Starfield
myStars = []            # An (initially) empty list
for i in range(1000):
    x = random.randint(0, 800)
    y = random.randint(0, 600)
    newStar = [x, y]    # A 2-element list
    myStars.append(newStar)
starSpeed = 100.0       # Rate of star movement (px / s)
starDirection = 0       # 0 = not moving, -1 = left, +1 = right

#input
while not done: 
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        done = True

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            debug = not debug


    dt = clock.tick() /1000.0

#the missile range (making it disappear after it hits the top)
    for missile in missiles:
        missile[1] -= missileSpeed * dt 
        if missile[1] < 0:    missiles.remove(missle)


#triangle following mouse position
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if mx > launchX:
        launchX += .3
    if mx < launchX:
        launchX -= .3


#bullets firing when pressing with mouse
    mbuttons = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if mbuttons [0]:
        x = launchX
        y = launchY
        newMissiles = [x,y]
        missiles.append(newMissiles)

#Creating the UFOs
    ufoSpawnTimer -= dt
    if ufoSpawnTimer <= 0:
        if random.choice (("head", "tail")) == "head":
            x = 0
            hspeed = random.randint (10,50)
        else:
            x = 800
            hspeed = random.randint (-50, -10)
        y = random.randint (0,300)
        new_ufo = [x,y,hspeed]
        ufo_list.append(new_ufo)
        ufoSpawnTimer = 5.0


#Moving the Starfield
    for i in range(len(myStars)):
        myStars[i][0] += starSpeed * dt * starDirection
        if myStars[i][0] < 0:       myStars[i][0] = 800
        if myStars[i][0] > 800:     myStars[i][0] = 0   



    screen.fill ((0,0,0))
#drawing the triangle  a.k.a missle launcher :D
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (255,255,255), [[launchX, launchY], [launchX + 10, launchY + 10], \
                        [launchX - 10, launchY + 10]], 3)

    for missile in missiles:
        x = int(missile[0])
        y = int(missile[1])
        screen.blit(rocket, (x,y))


    #drawing the ufo
    for v in ufo_list:
        v[0] += v[2] * dt
        screen.blit(ufo,(v[0],v[1]))


    #Missle distance from UFO  - NEED HELP ON THIS PORTION
    #Hit Detection
    missileDist = ((x - v[0]) ** 2 + (y - v[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5
    if **????** :
        ufoRespawn = True
        ufoHits += 10

    #drawing th starfield
    for star in myStars:
        x = int(star[0])
        y = int(star[1])
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,255,255), (x,y), 2)



    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.font.quit()
pygame.display.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Well there are many different ways to detect collision, And it might be worth looking at libraries that would do so, but the simplest method by far is to use `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`.

But before I can show how to use the function, you need to know what a `pygame.sprite.Group()` is and what a sprite class is.

Basicly, what a `pygame.sprite.Group()` is, is a way to keep track of and hold multiple sprites. In your case, it seems making a missile group for your missiles would be the best choice.

So I would create a group to hold your missiles:
`missiles_group = pygame.sprite.Group()`. You can add missiles to the group by saying `missiles_group.add(<sprite instance name>)`.

As for the sprite class, please see this answer I gave to a question. To be terse, a Sprite class is a modular way to create a sprite. Instead of using just  a plain image, a sprite class would hold necessary methods and attributes of a sprite. I will be using a sprite class in my example below, so if more detail is needed, please read the answer I linked to above.

---

With that out of the way, and without going into too much detail, here is how you fill in each function parameter to the above function.

- `sprite`: This is the sprite that will be tested against a group of sprites
- `group`: This is the group that will be used to test with the sprite.
- `dokill`: This is a boolean value. If set to true, each time the `sprite` parameter collides with something in the `group` parameter, and object from the group parameter will be deleted. And visa versa if the `dokill` argument is set to false.
  The is one more parameter that the function takes, but for what you're trying to do, it is not needed.

Incorporating the above information, here is an example. The example creates a sprite and a list of sprites. Each time the sprite collides with a sprite from the group, `HIT` is printed to the screen:

```
import pygame #import the pygame module into the namespace <module>

WIDTH = 640 # define a constant width for our window
HEIGHT = 480 # define a constant height for our window

#create a pygame window, and
#initialize it with our WIDTH and HEIGHT constants
display = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock() # create a game clock

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT / 2
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0

    def update(self):
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.vx = -1
        elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.vx = 1
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.vy = -1
        elif key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.vy = 1
        self.rect.x += self.vx
        self.rect.y += self.vy

# cretae a player sprite
player = Sprite()

# create a group to hold all of our sprites
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

# create a group to hold sprites we want to
# test collions against. These sprites will
# still be added to the sprites list
# but we need a seperate group to test for
# collisions against
collision_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

# add a sprite to out collison sprite group
# We also add the sprite to our sprites group
# that holds all sprites
tmp = Sprite()
tmp.update = lambda: None
sprites.add(tmp)
collision_sprites.add(tmp)

# add a player sprites to the player group
player.rect.x = 10
sprites.add(player)


running = True # our variable for controlling our game loop
while running:
    for e in pygame.event.get(): # iterate ofver all the events pygame is tracking
        clock.tick(60) # make our clock keep pour game at 60 FPS
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT: # is the user trying to close the window?
            running = False # if so break the loop
            pygame.quit() # quit the pygame module
            quit() # quit is for IDLE friendliness

    sprites.update()

    # here is where we test for collision
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, collision_sprites, False):
        print("HIT!")

    display.fill((180, 180, 180)) # fill the pygame screen with white
    sprites.draw(display)
    pygame.display.flip() # update the screen
```

My example if fairly big, so take your time and step through it carefully. I tried to add as many good comments as I could. Good luck!

Comment: @Allison if you don't want to use [Sprites](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) yet then use at least [pygame.Rect()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and `pygame.Rect.colliderect()`

Comment: @furas Yeah I guess he could. But since he was already loading in images, i figured he might as well use Sprites.

Comment: yes, sooner or later OP will have to learn Sprites - so with your example OP can start it now.